# Xamarin Forms iOS and Android projects not able to run In Mac?

Tags: c#, ios, macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

The below are the issues I am getting when I am cleaning and Building the project.

> When we are running the project iOS or Android both is occurring same
> error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Current/Microsoft.Common.props(3,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "/Users/…..iOS/obj/ABSConfigurator.iOS.csproj.*.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration “ABSConfigurator.iOS.csproj.*.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019)
```

> When I am restoring the package then below are the error:

```
Error: NuGet packages need to be restored before building. NuGet MSBuild targets are missing and are needed for building. The NuGet MSBuild targets are generated when the NuGet packages are restored.
```

Comment: You can try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it .  If it doesn’t work  ,try to restart the VS .

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT: I have tried delete bin / obj folder, clean the project, close and reopen visual studio, restoring packages, etc,... but no use. It is showing same issue.

Comment: Is  your visual studio preview version?